# Functions and Relations Studying Help. What does the R mean??

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

The Question:

[image]

The Example:

[image]

Hi,

So I've been trying to figure out what exactly the R means in this context. Does it mean f1 mod f = some n or f1 - f = f mod f1 etc.? I would be very thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not some strange modular thing, but a well-known relation that is widely used when studying asymptotics. $f\mathrel{\mathscr R}g$ means that there is a positive real number $c$ and natural number $N$ such that $|f(n)| \leq c\cdot |g(n)|$ for all $n > N$. In more intuitive terms, $f$ is "not much larger" than $g$ as $n\to \infty$.

To take the example $f(n) = n$ and $g(n) = n+5$, we have $f(n) \leq g(n)$ for all $n$, so $f\mathrel{\mathscr R}g$. We also have $g(n) \leq 5f(n)$ for all $n$, so $g\mathrel{\mathscr R}f$.

Comment: So could f1 be 2n, f2 be 3n, and f3 be 4n?

Comment: In other words as long as n is raised to only the first power (Not n^2 or n^3 etc) the function works.

Comment: @Will: In fact for (a) you can use $an^r$ for any $a>0$ and $r\ge 1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So what are a couple examples of functions that wouldn't work?

Comment: @Will: $\sqrt{n}$, $\ln n$: both grow slower than any linear function.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott For (a), you can't have $ax^r$ for $r \neq 1$, because we want both $f\mathrel{\mathscr R}f_i$ and $f_i\mathrel{\mathscr R}f$. For (b), on the other hand, $ax^r$ for $r<1$ will work.

Comment: @Arthur: Oops: I didn’t read carefully enough and missed the second requirement. You are of course quite right.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I see that I forgot the absolute value signs, and I'm happy you put them in there, but do you really have to specify that $c$ is _positive_?

Comment: @Arthur: Technically not, once the absolute value signs are there, but it seems simpler and clearer to specify that fact up front, at least from a pædagogical point of view.